# Compiling a Maven plugin using the help-mojo phase with maven-plugin-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm working on an extension of a [MojoHaus plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin) for Maven.
My project is at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ozimov/yaml-properties-maven-plugin).

When I try to run `mvn clean install`, the compilation fails with the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.4:helpmojo 
(help-mojo) on project yaml-properties-maven-plugin: Execution help-mojo of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.4:helpmojo failed: syntax error @[11,22] in 
file:/home/user/workspace/yaml-properties-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/properties/ResourceType.java -> [Help 1]
```

The class `ResourceType` looks like:

```
package org.codehaus.mojo.properties;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public enum ResourceType {

    PROPERTIES(".properties"),
    YAML(new String[]{".yml", ".yaml"});

    private final Set<String> fileExtensions;

    ResourceType(final String... fileExtensions) {
        this.fileExtensions = new HashSet<String>();
        for(final String fileExtension: fileExtensions){
            this.fileExtensions.add(fileExtension);
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> allFileExtensions(final ResourceType... resourceTypes) {
        final Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<String>();
        for (final ResourceType resourceType : resourceTypes) {
            extensions.addAll(resourceType.fileExtensions());
        }

        return extensions;
    }

    public static ResourceType getByFileName(final String fileName) {
        for (final ResourceType resourceType : ResourceType.values()) {
            for (final String extension : resourceType.fileExtensions()) {
                if (fileName.endsWith(extension)) {
                    return resourceType;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Set<String> fileExtensions() {
        return new HashSet<String>(fileExtensions);
    }

}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're hitting an issue with QDox, which probably has an issue with parsing the line `YAML(new String[]{".yml", ".yaml"});`. The stacktrace can confirm that.
The solution is actually quite simple since you're using varArgs: change the line to `YAML(".yml", ".yaml");`

Comment: I didn't think about it! Thanks a lot